# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' (for json data with python)

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I have the same site with same json structure. It works for one but doesn't work for second link. What is the reason? What is the logic of "group(1)"

Code

```
import requests, re, json

r1 = requests.get('https://www.trendyol.com/apple/macbook-air-13-m1-8gb-256gb-ssd-altin-p-67940132').text
r2 = requests.get('https://www.trendyol.com/lenovo/v15-82nb003gtx-i5-10210u-8gb-512gb-mx330-ssd-15-6-fhd-windows-10-home-dizustu-bilgisayar-p-320147814').text

json_data1 = json.loads(re.search(r"window.__PRODUCT_DETAIL_APP_INITIAL_STATE__=({.*}});window", r1).group(1))
print('json_data1:',json_data1['product']['attributes'][0]['value']['name'])
print('-------')
json_data2 = json.loads(re.search(r"window.__PRODUCT_DETAIL_APP_INITIAL_STATE__=({.*}});window", r2).group(1))
print('json_data2:',json_data2['product']['attributes'][0]['value']['name'])
```

Output

```
json_data1: Apple M1
-------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cucal/Desktop/scraper.py", line 33, in <module>
    json_data2 = json.loads(re.search(r"window.__PRODUCT_DETAIL_APP_INITIAL_STATE__=({.*}});window", r2).group(1))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
[Finished in 453ms with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['python3', '-u', '/Users/cucal/Desktop/scraper.py']]
[dir: /Users/cucal/Desktop]
[path: /opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you see the diffence,

```
In [1]: re.search(r"window.__PRODUCT_DETAIL_APP_INITIAL_STATE__=({.*}});window", r1)
Out[1]: <re.Match object; span=(136194, 164410), match='window.__PRODUCT_DETAIL_APP_INITIAL_STATE__={"pro>

In [2]: re.search(r"window.__PRODUCT_DETAIL_APP_INITIAL_STATE__=({.*}});window", r2)
```

The first one returns `None` That means there is no matching for the `regex` you provided there. That's why you got error for second one.

**What is `group(1)` in your regex?**

Here is the representation.
[image]

**For the second sample you have to do like this,**

```
matches = re.search(r"window.__PRODUCT_DETAIL_APP_INITIAL_STATE__\s=\s({.*}})", r2)
if matches:
    json_data2 = json.loads(matches.group(1))
    print('json_data2:',json_data2['product']['attributes'][0]['value']['name'])
```

Which output:

```
json_data2: Intel Core i5
```

And if you observe the second webpage source, it has spaces before the `=` so you need to adjust the regex accordingly.

New regex for the second sample, ['regex_demo'](https://www.debuggex.com/r/5mbcB92AJmc8WQEW)

```
r"window.__PRODUCT_DETAIL_APP_INITIAL_STATE__\s=\s({.*}})"
```

Comment: I take the json from here https://www.trendyol.com/lenovo/v15-82nb003gtx-i5-10210u-8gb-512gb-mx330-ssd-15-6-fhd-windows-10-home-dizustu-bilgisayar-p-320147814 in script tag. why it returns "None" i don't understand

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't know how to align regex. r"window.__PRODUCT_DETAIL_APP_INITIAL_STATE__\s=\s({.*}})"   \s =means space?

Comment: @piseynir `\s` means one space. In the given example if you check the source code(`view page source`) and do a simple find  `(ctrl+f)` this string `window.__PRODUCT_DETAIL_APP_INITIAL_STATE__`. You can see the spacing given there so you need to write regex accordingly.  
I would suggest checking this on your both samples so you can see the difference.

Comment: Sample_1: `window.__PRODUCT_DETAIL_APP_INITIAL_STATE__={"product"` Sample_2: `window.__PRODUCT_DETAIL_APP_INITIAL_STATE__ = {"product":`